# How to estimate probit model with binary endogenous regressor using Stata

Tags: stata

The theoretical principle behind the estimation is clear to me (as is described on Wooldridge's textbook and  some previous threads][1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48922/estimating-two-stage-selection-model-with-probit-reduced-form-equation-and-ols-s/48957#48957))

[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48922/estimating-two-stage-selection-model-with-probit-reduced-form-equation-and-ols-s/48957#48957): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94063/probit-two-stage-least-squares/94392#94392. However when I check the Stata manual of `ivprobit`,it writes

```
"···regressors are continuous and are not appropriate for use with discrete endogenous
regressors."
```

So I wonder if there is some other (built-in or user-written)command that can be used to implement to estimate such model (**binary** endogenous regressor).

---

Thank you for your useful suggestion. A further question: if I want to estimate Heckman selection model with binary endogenous variable, something like what's discussed in this thread [two-stage selection model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48922/estimating-two-stage-selection-model-with-probit-reduced-form-equation-and-ols-s/48957#48957), 
which command can I use? `cmp`? (the syntax of this command is complicated and confusing to me). Or can I just add inverse Mills ratio to the rhs and use `biprobit` as suggested by @drstevok?

Comment: If this question is about finding Stata packages, it is off-topic (see our FAQ to learn more about what is considered on-topic here). You will have to reframe this as a statistical software-agnostic question, otherwise I'm afraid it will be closed.

Comment: Simply using linear 2SLS will also do the trick. See this article by Angrist (2001), http://piketty.pse.ens.fr/files/Angrist2001b.pdf

Comment: Questions with no code just about which command to use are a poor fit on SO. Use Statalist for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `biprobit` command. There's a nice explanation by Austin Nichols [here](http://www.stata.com/meeting/chicago11/materials/chi11_nichols.pdf).